# Double clicking OS X app bundle built with pyinstaller doesn't open the app, but running executable from within the bundle works. What's wrong?

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller, app-bundle

When I try to build this [app](https://gitlab.com/mindfulness-at-the-computer/mindfulness-at-the-computer/blob/master/mindfulness-at-the-computer-macos.spec) on OS X with pyinstaller the app bundle doesn't work.

Double clicking on the bundle from the finder doesn't do anything.

- OS version: OS X High Sierra 10.13.6
- python: 3.6.3
- pyinstaller: 3.3.1 (also tried 3.4.dev0+380ab20f8)

I built the app as follows: `pyinstaller --windowed mindfulness-at-the-computer-macos.spec`

When searching for answers I found (among other things) the following posts, but they didn't help much

- [PyInstaller OS X app runs from command line, but not Finder window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176169/pyinstaller-os-x-app-runs-from-command-line-but-not-finder-window)
- [mac os x app bundle built from pyinstaller doesn't work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328703/mac-os-x-app-bundle-built-from-pyinstaller-doesnt-work-correctly)

To make sure the problem isn't in our code I tried building a simple example as outlined in this document (scroll all the way down for the code):

https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/runtime-information.html#run-time-information

This has the same problem.

I built it like this: `pyinstaller -w directories.py`

When I run it with python I get this:

`python directories.py`

```
we are not frozen
bundle dir is /Users/marieke/myprojects/test
sys.argv[0] is directories.py
sys.executable is /Users/marieke/myprojects/test/venv/bin/python
os.getcwd is /Users/marieke/myprojects/test
```

When I run it in the terminal from /Users/marieke/myprojects/test/dist/directories.app/Contents/MacOS

`./directories`

```
we are ever so frozen
bundle dir is /Users/marieke/myprojects/test/dist/directories.app/Contents/MacOS
sys.argv[0] is ./directories
sys.executable is /Users/marieke/myprojects/test/dist/directories.app/Contents/MacOS/directories
os.getcwd is /Users/marieke/myprojects/test/dist/directories.app/Contents/MacOS
```

When I run it in the finder from /Users/marieke/myprojects/test/dist/directories.app/Contents/MacOS

`/Users/marieke/myprojects/test/dist/directories.app/Contents/MacOS/directories ; exit;`

```
we are ever so frozen
bundle dir is /Users/marieke/myprojects/test/dist/directories.app/Contents/MacOS
sys.argv[0] is /Users/marieke/myprojects/test/dist/directories.app/Contents/MacOS/directories
sys.executable is /Users/marieke/myprojects/test/dist/directories.app/Contents/MacOS/directories
os.getcwd is /Users/marieke
```

When I double click the bundle it doesn't run.
When I run `open -a directories.app` from the terminal it doesn't run either.

In the console app I only see a launchservicesd message `CHECKIN:0x0-0x97097 5878 directories`. Nothing else.

Access rights of the binary are -rwxr-xr-x@

The `Info.plist` file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict><key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>directories</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>directories</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>directories</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>MacOS/directories</string>
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>icon-windowed.icns</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>0.0.0</string>
<key>LSBackgroundOnly</key>
<string>0</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The funny thing is, until 3 months ago we were able to build a working bundle. So in the meantime apparently something strange happened which I can't find yet.

I would be very thankful for some help!

Comment: Use Py2App instead. I never had problems with it. Your App is a GUI app, I hope. Because you need the application object to start the thing. Bundles aren't terminal applications and will not start the console window, its stderr and stdout will hopefully be redirected to the system log. It does not matter if the plist says it is a background job. You need an App with the main loop to interact with system events. In fact, it is better to switch to background inside of a program than defining the bundle as the background process. Perhaps your problem is that the bundle is run in a background.

Comment: @Dalen thank you. Py2App works nicely!